# Is macOS app setting.bundle file similar as iPhone app setting.bundle file?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am developing a Mac app.
I hope store some data to system setting where I use the code to access

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:  [settingMutableDictionary objectForKey:myObject ] forKey:@"myKey"];
```

I try to copy the iPhone app Setting.bundle file to my macOS project, but When I opened the file Root.plist, it displayed

```
'iPhone Settings Scheme"
```

This is not what I want.

your comment welcome

[image: **enter image description here**]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`macOS` does not use a `settings.bundle` like `iOS`, it uses a standard `.plist` generally stored in `$HOME/Library/Preferences/`. The `.plist` takes on the name of the bundle identifier:

```
<ApplicationBundleIdentifer>.plist
```

↳ [Preferences and Settings Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AboutPreferenceDomains/AboutPreferenceDomains.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH2-96980)